# New column to pandas dataframe according to values from other column

Tags: pandas

I have a column in my data frame with string data. I need to create a new column of integers, one for each unique string. I will use this column as the second level of a multiindex. The code below does the trick, but I was wondering if there could be a more efficient solution in Pandas for it?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[1,2,3,4],
                   'c2':['a','a','b','b']})

for i,e in enumerate(df.c2.unique()):
    df.loc[df.c2 == e,'c3'] = i
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i,e in enumerate(df.c2.unique()):
    df.loc[df.c2 == e,'c3'] = i
```

can be replaced with

```
df['c3'] = pd.Categorical(df['c2']).codes
```

---

Even for this small DataFrame, using Categorical is (about 4x) quicker:

```
In [33]: %%timeit
...:     for i,e in enumerate(df.c2.unique()):
             df.loc[df.c2 == e,'c3'] = i
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 ms per loop

In [35]: %timeit pd.Categorical(df['c2']).codes
1000 loops, best of 3: 264 µs per loop
```

The improvement in speed will increase with the number of unique elements in `df['c2']` since the Python `for-loop`'s relative inefficency will become more apparent with more iterations.

For example, if

```
import string
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':np.arange(N),
                   'c2':np.random.choice(list(string.letters), size=N)})
```

then using Categorical is (about 56x) quicker:

```
In [53]: %%timeit
....:     for i,e in enumerate(df.c2.unique()):
              df.loc[df.c2 == e,'c3'] = i
10 loops, best of 3: 58.2 ms per loop

In [54]: %timeit df['c3'] = pd.Categorical(df['c2']).codes
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 ms per loop
```

The benchmarks above were done with [IPython's](http://ipython.org/) %timeit "magic function".